# better way of changing iframe url through DOM in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, angular

I'm trying to replace a `URL` using `(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("workflow")).src` however I don't think this is the right way of doing it.

Also tried the code below but its giving me `getElementById` of undefined.

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Inject } from '@angular/core';
constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef){}


 this.elementRef.nativeElement.document.getElementById("workflow").src = "./javascript/workfloweditor.html?title="+workFlowTitle;
```

Can someone point out how to do this properly in Angular 2?

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe [src]="iframeSrc">
```

```
constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer) {
}

get iframeSrc() {
  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('./javascript/workfloweditor.html?title='+workFlowTitle);
  // or
  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('./javascript/workfloweditor.html?title='+workFlowTitle);
}
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizer-class.html

Comment: Thanks, will this this answer.